# Javascript - Hide Dynamic Div based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that creates dynamic Divs with ID's that enumerate as they are created similar to the below HTML:

```
<div id="dgpCheckDiv10_0">
    <input Delete
</div>

<div id="dgpCheckDiv10_1">
    text2
</div>
```

Certain Div's will have checkboxes that have the word 'Delete' as noted above and other Div's will have a checkbox that doesn't have a label at all.

I'm trying to write some javascript that will hide those checkboxes that don't contain the word 'Delete'.

I have the following script but it's not hitting the .hide function.  Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; ++i) {
        console.log(divs[i].id);
        //if(divs[i].id.substring(divs[i].id.length) == 'dgpCheckDiv10_*') {
        if(/^dgpCheckDiv10_/.test(divs[i].id)) {
            if(divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf(" Delete") === -1) {
                console.log(divs[i].innerHTML);
                $(divs[i]).hide();
                //$(this).closest('#divDGP2Container').find('#task').hide();
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: 1st, there's something wrong with your <input>, can you guess what?

Comment: The name of a checkbox is in its `value` attribute -- inputs don't have `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide the DIVs that don't contain a checkbox whose value is `Delete`.

```
$("div[id^=dgpCheckDiv10_]:not(:contains(:checkbox[value=Delete]))").hide();
```

If you just want to hide the checkboxes, not the whole DIV:

```
$("div[id^=dgpCheckDiv10_] :checkbox:not([value=Delete])").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do :

```
<div id="dgpCheckDiv10_0">
 <input type="checkbox"/>Delete
</div>

<div id="dgpCheckDiv10_1">
<input type="checkbox"/>
</div>

$("div[id^='dgpCheckDiv10']").each(function()
{
    if($(this).html().indexOf("Delete") === -1)
    {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').hide();
        // If you wish to remove it - just uncomment the following line
        //$(this).html("");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uj0twtd8/1/